# Отправка уведомлений на e-mail. Правильное решение

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

В веб-приложении пользователи получают уведомления после наступления различных событий.
Теперь необходимо реализовать отправку уведомлений и на e-mail адрес пользователей.

Проблема следующая:

В некоторых местах программы для вставки уведомления в таблицу используется функция (написанная на PHP, которая тоже может отправлять письмо на почту), в других (а их очень много) используется непосредственно метод для вставки записи в таблицу (метод query класса PDO) - что-то вроде INSERT INTO notifications...

Чтобы в каждом файле не менять этот запрос на вызов функции, придумал такое решение:
Сейчас в программе, в каждом PHP-файле подключается общий файл с различными функциями и классами.

В этом общем файле с помощью функции register_shutdown_function зарегистрировать функцию, которая будет делать запрос к таблице с уведомлениями и проверять на наличие новых уведомлений. Если они есть, то отправлять их и на e-mail.

Стоит ли так делать? Может есть решение лучше?

Comment: Лучше отправку почты делать независимым от приходящих web-запросов образом. что бы не тормозить их. Запускать задачу рассылки по крону или если уведомлений много и отправлять их надо часто запустить отдельный процесс который будет заниматься рассылкой и спать на sleep когда работы нет

Comment: А который из этих способов лучше, если, например, нужно проверять таблицу с уведомлениями на наличие новых уведомлений каждые 5 секунд?

Comment: Разницы наверное не будет, да?

Comment: Ну раз в 5 сек запускать новый процесс как то тяжко для системы. Да и cron работает раз в 5 минут вроде. Если так часто - точно отдельный, постоянно запущенный процесс

Comment: Спасибо!
Только немного непонятен этот момент:
"будет заниматься рассылкой и спать на sleep когда работы нет"
А как процесс сможет определить есть работа или нет?
Код, проверяющий записи в таблице, будет запускаться с интервалом в 5 с. и просто проверять таблицу с уведомлениями.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php